# How to symbolize a vector with its elements function of time in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve some differential equations in this form

dU/dt=A*U, where U is a vector of N elements and N is an input from the user

So U=[u1(t);u2(t)...uN(t)], A is NxN matrix

I want to have a vector (U) its elements u1,u2..uN are function of time

I can define U as follows

```
U=sym('u',[N 1]);
```

This is the output:

```
u1
u2
.
.
uN
```

And if I write this

```
eqn= diff(U)==A*U;
U=dsolve(eqn);
```

This is the error I got

```
{Error using symengine (line 58)
Could not extract differential variables to solve for. Use 'solve' or
 'vpasolve' to compute the solutions of non-differential equations.

 Error in mupadengine/feval (line 155)
symengine('error',S(8:find(S=='[',1)-2));

 Error in dsolve>mupadDsolve (line 325)
 T = feval(symengine,'symobj::dsolve',sys,x,options);

 Error in dsolve (line 186)
 sol = mupadDsolve(args, options);
}
```

He treats the elements of U vector as just a variable not function of time

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) and regular expressions to create the string `'[u1(t);u2(t); ... ]'`:

```
str= mat2str((1:N).');     % create the string '[1;2;...;N]'
% replace the digit sequences with 'u<digit sequence>(t)'
str= regexprep(str,'(\d)+','u$&(t)');  
u= sym(str);
```

Comment: Thank you 
with
    eqn= diff(u)== A*u
output
    diff(u1(t), t) == u1(t) + 2*u2(t)
   diff(u2(t), t) == u2(t) - u1(t)
 
but dsolve()
    u = dsolve(eqn)

{Error using symengine (line 58) Could not extract differential variables to solve for. Use 'solve' or 'vpasolve' to compute the solutions of non-differential equations.
Error in mupadengine/feval (line 155)                    symengine('error',S(8:find(S=='[',1)-2));

Error in dsolve>mupadDsolve (line 325)
T = feval(symengine,'symobj::dsolve',sys,x,options);
Error in dsolve (line 186)
sol = mupadDsolve(args, options);
}

Comment: @Marwa Saeed :( Sorry, I don't know how to help you. That code works for me (I have MATLAB R2015b installed)

Comment: Thank you very much
Would you show me the results of using the dsolve()?